# How should I deal with an answer that's only partially applicable and low quality?

Tags: discussion, closing

We've all seen posted answers that aren't relevant to the question. There has been wide discussion about not voting to delete incorrect answers, enough to the point where text has been added to say "[close] flags should not be used to indicate incorrect answers." What should we do about answers [like this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/380522/228910)* which is *probably correct on the user's modded Minecraft server* but not helpful to the general Minecraft playerbase.

The answer is indubitably low quality as it is both short (23 words long), and has spelling errors. But what should be done? It could be rescued with an edit that corrects the spelling and better indicates that mods could be used as a solution, but it could also be deleted because of it's current quality.

Is it worth the effort to rescue a question that isn't helpful to most players, should it be closed and  make it not our problem, or should I just downvote and move on?

<sub>* Answer is now deleted. [Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7MMU.png) for those < 10k rep)</sub>

Comment: Did this post appear in your VLQ review queue? The answer you're talking about may have already been deleted. If it did show up in the queue, could you find the deleted answer and paste its content here?

Comment: I didn't vote to close it because I wasn't sure how to deal with the answer, but yes I notice it is gone now too. From memory the answer was something like "put the player in ssouldand and surround them with lazers. then u can put the house in obsidian"

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 & PausePause - I've added a screenshot for you.